# How to get the data from a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Let me explain my problem:

I have a web application following the MVC pattern.

There is a main view showing a schedule. (Content isnt really important for this question).
There is a "New meeting" button.
This button opens a modal. In fact, it reloads the view with a paramater to show the modal. This all works pretty fine.

In the modal there are some input fields for adding a meeting to the schedule and a button to save the entered data as a new meeting.

The submit button doesnt do anything when hit. 
Is there another way to get the data of the modal into a controller?

Here is my code: (truncated)

**index.view**

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   

    <div class="container">
    the schedule table 
<div>
 
  
  **the modal** 
  
  <div id="dialog-modal" class="ui-dialog modal modal" title="Test" style="overflow-x:hidden">

    <div class="container form-group">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="row" style="z-index:15">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <h3>Neue Besprechung</h3>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Titel)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">

                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Titel, new { @class = "form-control col-xs-5", width = "100%" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Termin)
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-append date col-xs-5" form-control>

                        <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control col-xs-5" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" value=@Model.SelectedDate>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Starttime)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <select name="Beginn" class="form-control col-xs-5">
                            @foreach (var zeit in Model.CurrentBesprechung.Stundenblatt)
                            {
                                if (@zeit.Value == "")
                                {
                                    <option>@zeit.Key</option>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <option disabled="disabled">@zeit.Key - @zeit.Value</option>

                                }

                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Endtime)
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <select name="Ende" class="form-control col-xs-5">
                            @foreach (var zeit in Model.CurrentBesprechung.Stundenblatt)
                            {
                                if (@zeit.Value == "")
                                {
                                    <option>@zeit.Key</option>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <option disabled="disabled">@zeit.Key - @zeit.Value</option>

                                }

                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label>Raum</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <select name="Raum" class="form-control col-xs-5">
                            @foreach (var room in Model.RoomList)
                            {
                                if (room.RaumID == Model.SelectedRoom.RaumID)
                                {
                                    <option selected="selected">@room.Beschreibung</option>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <option>@room.Beschreibung</option>
                                }

                            }
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label>Ersteller</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Ersteller, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label>Beschreibung</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.CurrentBesprechung.Beschreibung, new { @class = "form-control", rows = "5" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    
    **the submit button**
    
    
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn" />
      <div class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" data-dismiss="modal">Senden!</div>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
  
  }
```

Comment: First thing is you can use HtmlBeginform/AjaxForm using submit button (what you are using) otherwise you can simply place a button with typle="button" and make an ajax call by post method. This will do the same..

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `AJAX` to send the datas to your controller if you are using a modal

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      var formDatas = $('#formId').serialize(); //Gets the form datas
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "your controler path",
          data: {formDatas:formDatas},
          dataType: 'html',
          success: function(response){
           //Do whatever you want to do
          }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the data to a controller, you should encapsulate all your form fields in a form and all your input fields should have a name.

```
<form method="POST" action="Your/Controller/Here">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="exampleInputField" value="abcd" />

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Close" class="btn" />
        <div class="btn btn-default" type="Submit" data-dismiss="modal">Senden!</div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

As you can see from the above code, both the modal body and modal footer are inside a form.

You can get the data as (**this is different for different languages**)

```
params.exampleInputField
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap all of your input fields and the submit button in a form element.

The form element should have an action pointing to your controller url.

E.g.

```
<div id="dialog-modal">
    <form action="/path/to/myController" method="post">
        ... input fields ...
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: tried this, without effect (on different "locations" inside the view)

Comment: The form element needs to wrap the other elements within your modal. So in that regard there's only one correct "location" for it... the modal itself can appear almost anywhere.

Comment: Also note that the ajax solution above is ultimately better, but let's walk before we try to run eh?
Ajax has its own set of complexities, and the questioner is struggling with basic forms right now...